# I am adding a user review/rate to my laravel 9 application but when I click on the rate button I get 404| not found. No help after search online

Tags: laravel, review, rate

**The function name is store and it is the same in the blade view. One user can rate many products and the user must be logged in before getting access to rate**

Here is the blade codes

```
    <h2>{{ $product->name }}</h2>

<p>{{ $product->description }}</p>

<h3>Reviews</h3>

<ul>
    @foreach ($product->reviews as $review)
        <li>{{ $review->review }} - {{ $review->rating }} stars</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>

<h3>Add a Review</h3>

<form method="POST" action="/products/{{ $product->id }}/reviews">
    @csrf

    <div>
        <label for="review">Review</label>
        <textarea name="review" id="review">{{ old('review') }}</textarea>

        @error('review')
            <div>{{ $message }}</div>
        @enderror
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="rating">Rating</label>
        <input type="number" name="rating" id="rating" min="1" max="5" value="{{ old('rating') }}">

        @error('rating')
            <div>{{ $message }}</div>
        @enderror
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Submit Review</button>
</form>
```

**Controller. A user can rate between 1-5 for a single product**

```
public function store(Product $product)
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'review' => 'required|string',
            'rating' => 'required|integer|min:1|max:5',
        ]);

        $review = new Review($data);
        $review->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $product->reviews()->save($review);

        return back();
```

**route**

```
Route::post('/products/{product}/reviews', [HomeController::class, 'store']);
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::post('/products/{product}/reviews', [HomeController::class, 'store']);
```

**Database**

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->text('review');
            $table->integer('rating');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your error with:

Adding a name to your route :

```
Route::post('/products/{product}/reviews', [HomeController::class, 'store'])->name('store.review');
```

Update the action of your form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('store.review', ['product' => $product->id]) }}">
```

Comment: The same error persist

Comment: Why you got 2 times the same route ? A public route and another under a middleware ?

Comment: I changed it to the one you suggested to me